# Изменять ссылку после обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста как поменять ссылку после того как пользователь обновил страницу? Т.е. есть код:

```
<div id="footer_menu">
            <center><a href="#ссылка" title="текст">Текст2</a></center>
        </div>
```

И мне нужно, чтобы после обновления страницы была другая ссылка, которую увидит пользователь. Например:

```
   <center><a href="#ссылка" title="текст">Текст2</a></center>
```

Как это реализовать не могу понять.

Comment: для подсказки: нужно использовать local storage.

Comment: Можно при нажатии на ссылку отправить POST запрос, после обновления страницы сделать проверку, если в POST что то есть, то изменить ссылку.

Comment: Не по теме. Не надо использовать тег <center>: Использование этого элемента осуждается спецификацией HTML, вместо него применяйте стили.

Comment: как написано выше, лучше использовать local storage или session storage, смотря для чего нужно

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```js
if(localStorage.getItem("newlink")) {
 console.log('New link applied');
 document.getElementById("Link").href = localStorage.getItem("newlink");
} else {
 console.log('Creating new link');
 localStorage.setItem("newlink", "#link");
}
```

```css
#footer_menu {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 30px auto;
 border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
 width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer_menu">
 <a id="Link" href="#ссылка" title="текст">Текст2</a>
</div>
```